# Can't install Truffle sweet via Powershell on Windows 10. Get mkdirp 5.x deprecated and no more mainetained

Tags: powershell, ethereum

When I want to install the Truffle sweet  with `npm install -g Truffle` I get warnings which say that the mkdirp is deprecated and the package is broken and not maintained anymore.
So I think it won't install the truffle sweet.

What should I do to get the broken package fixed?

I am totally new to Ethereum programming.

The PowerShell code:

> mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: stable api reached

Comment: I think it's a pretty straight forward response.

Comment: Hi, do i need to update or use another code to install Truffle? Sorry i am a total newbie in this.